# Multi-Tenancy in Webforms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, multi-tenant

I have had success in implementing multi-tenancy in MVC applications using Saaskit. The applications have a separate db for each tenant. I would like to implement something similar in a webforms project. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Is it even possible?

Must have:

- Tenant detection based on domain/url
- Must support db per tenant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to use the new Unity support in Webforms 4.7.2 to support this:

```
public class TenantResolver : ITenantResolver
{

    public Tenant GetTenant()
    {

        var identifier = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.ToLower();

        return AllTenants().FirstOrDefault(x => x.HostNames.Any(a => a.Hostname.Contains(identifier)));

    }

    public List<Tenant> AllTenants()
    {

        // return list of tenants from configuration or seperate db

    }
}
```

**In Startup**

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    var container = this.AddUnity();

    container.RegisterType<ITenantResolver, TenantResolver>();
    container.RegisterType<ApplicationContext, ApplicationContext>();

}
```

**Example Page With Access to Tenant**

```
public partial class About : Page
{
    readonly Tenant tenant;
    readonly ApplicationContext _context;

    public About(ITenantResolver tenantresolver, ApplicationContext context)
    {
        tenant = tenantresolver.GetTenant();

        _context = context;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

**Example db context with db per Tenant**

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
    {

        public ApplicationContext(ITenantResolver tenantResolver) : base(ConnectionStringResolver(tenantResolver)) {

        }

        private string ConnectionStringResolver(AppTenant appTenant)
        {

            var tenant = tenantResolver.GetTenant();

            if (tenant != null)
            {

                return tenant.ConnectionString;

            }

            throw new NullReferenceException("Tenant Not Found");

        }

    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Default Membership API should suffice the requirements.

If not, consider http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider

Refer tutorials> http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials

Videos http://www.asp.net/security/videos

Best practices are explained in the above tutorials.

Comment: Can see that this was copied from a post in 2011...

https://forums.asp.net/t/1691865.aspx?Implementing+Multi+Tenancy+using+ASP+NET+Web+Forms+App

The 2nd and third links are now defunct.

Comment: Also may not be using membership it could be using Identity :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project